# append()'ing to an empty()'d ul

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clear a `<ul>` block of its `<li>` children, then `append()` new `<li>` to the empty `<ul>`.

I'm (attempting) to use OOP JS for this, so the jQuery to initiate the code further down is this:

```
$('#nav li a').click(function() {
    TutorGroupPoints.yearClick($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Part of the code in this `yearClick` function is:

```
$('#nav ul').empty();

for (var i = 0; i < this.Sorted.length; i++) {
    $('#nav ul').append('<li id="' + this.Sorted[i].id + '">' + this.Sorted[i].name + '</li>');
}
```

`this.Sorted` is an array of items which is fully populated.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <h2>Tutor Groups</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 9" id="9">Year 9</a></li>
        <li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 10" id="10">Year 10</a></li>
        <li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 11" id="11">Year 11</a></li>
        <li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 12" id="12">Year 12</a></li>
        <li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 13" id="13">Year 13</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

When I click on one of the `#nav li` anchors, it simply wipes the `<ul>` and doesn't `append()` any new `<li>`. **However**, if I comment the `empty` out, the new `<li>`s append to the existing `<li>`s correctly.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

**EDIT**

I've included `console.log` functions and nothing appears amiss.

[image: console.log]

The full text of `console.log` is:

```
[
    Object
    id: "12117"
    name: "11AB/Tp"
    __proto__: Object
    , 
    Object
    id: "12118"
    name: "11ABO/Tp"
    __proto__: Object ,
    Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object ,  Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object
] compiler.php:32
<li id="12117">11AB/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12118">11ABO/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12119">11AN/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12605">11DR/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12626">11DST/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12149">11JOR/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12150">11LLU/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12151">11MDA/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12152">11ND/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12153">11PD/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12154">11RJ/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12606">11SDI/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12155">11ST/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12607">11SW/Tp</li> compiler.php:38
<li id="12156">11VY/Tp</li>
```

The full code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/U16SjaD8). I didn't include it originally because it uses VLE-specific API calls which tend to confuse matters if you're not familiar with them.

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is `#nav` the `ul` itself, or the parent element of the `#nav`?

Comment: Sorry, that was old code from me doing some testing. Edited my post with the "proper" rendition.

Comment: So if you add `console.log(this.Sorted.length)` just before the loop you see...what?

Comment: log the `this.Sorted` variable before the loop.. and put a log inside the for loop to check if he gets there..(it probably won't)

Comment: @VDP I can't check right now (IT technicians have just killed my server..) but I've edited my OP to state, `However, if I comment the empty out, the new <li>s append to the existing <li>s correctly.`

Comment: Your code worked fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Th7p8/

Comment: I've added the full code and `console.log` readings to my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've shown the ACTUAL code and ACTUAL HTML, we can see that you are doing:

```
$('#nav').empty();
```

And, then trying to append to:

```
$('#nav ul')
```

But, the `.empty()` removed the `ul` so the `$('#nav ul')` is an empty jQuery object (finds nothing in your page) so trying to append to it doesn't do anything.  That also explains why removing the `.empty()` line lets the `.append()` work.

Change:

```
$('#nav').empty();
```

to:

```
$('#nav ul').empty();
```

Comment: To be honest, I can't quite fathom it. I've been using the `#nav ul` selector on everything in my code all morning - to no avail. I then changed it to `#nav` just to see what happened (obviously that didn't work) and forgot to change the code when I pasted it here. Strangely, now that I've reverted it, it's working. I'm wondering if I typo'd somewhere or something. So frustrating - thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: @dunc - I hope you can see that this problem took only a few minutes to spot when you showed your ACTUAL code and HTML, but there was 45 mins of back and forth with no progress when you didn't show us the actual code.  Anyway, glad you got it sorted now.

Comment: I see your point of course - but strictly speaking you'd given me the same answer to this question about 30 seconds after I posted it! When I'm using the Frog APIs I try to avoid giving the full code (if I think I can get away with it) because you can't just throw it into jsFiddle and get it to work. I do my best to prepare the code so that people without access to those APIs can debug with me. Unfortunately, admittedly, this time I got it wrong. Cheers

Comment: @dunc - my point was that we all wasted 45 mins on this issue because you gave us incomplete and wrong information in the question.  There's never anything wrong with a reference to the ACTUAL code.  It only has the possibility of saving lots of time.  I added this comment because I see hundreds of questions a day that contain incomplete information and those questions make this site a lot less effective for everyone.

Comment: Wait, what? @dunc, I posted this solution yesterday as the first answer and you told me that was just a typo so I deleted my answer, and now it turns out it really was the problem? Oh well.

Comment: @nnnnnn - yeah, really bad question management by the OP.  Enormous amounts of wasted time by those trying to help because of bad and missing info.